# Send text with emoji from telegram bot to group using java

Tags: telegram-bot

I use the java library

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I use this java code to send message to a telegram group

```java
class MyBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot { ... }
...

MyBot bot = new MyBot...;
        bot.execute(new SendMessage(
                groupId,
                null,

                        "text with emoji \u1F601",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        ));
```

But the message in a group doesn't have an emoji. I try to use a byte notation string like this `\xF0\x9F\x93\xA7` but only that I recive in the group - that chars sequence not an emoji.

How to I can sent an emoji?